# Fill Internet Explorer Pop-Up Window with Excel Data

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I am filling fields with Excel data. This sub works for me on other websites.

How do I make this work for a pop-up window?

I have read a few other pages on this topic. I am using IE11.

This is an example of one of the fields I am trying to fill.

```
<input class="form-control" id="firstName" type="text" maxlength="250" data-bind="value:firstName,disable:$parent.readOnly">
```

```vb
Private Sub FillWebForm_xx_AddNewEE()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Dim xSheetName As String             

    xSheetName = "Company"

    MsgBox "Open Internet Explorer and navigate to the webpage that contains the fields to be filled, then click Okay."

    'Need to edit this I think: if k-window-title = "New Participant"

    Set ie = GetIE("https://xxx")

    'make browser visible (if existing instance of IE)
    ie.Visible = True

    'Get Window ID for IE so we can set it as activate window
    HWNDSrc = ie.hwnd

    'Set IE as Active Window
    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

    'Add a new employee
    ie.document.all("ssn").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("d32")

    ie.document.all("firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("e32")
    ie.document.all("lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("g32")
    'ie.document.all("suffix").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("h32")
    ie.document.all("dateId").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("i32").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ie.document.all("gender").Focus
    ie.document.all("gender").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("j32").Value
    'ie.document.all("gender").FireEvent ("onchange")
    'Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ie.document.all("address1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("k32")
    ie.document.all("address2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("l32")
    ie.document.all("city").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("m32")
    ie.document.all("state").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("n32")
    ie.document.all("zip").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("o32")
    'ie.document.all("country").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("p32")
    'ie.document.all("email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("tbd")
    'ie.document.all("hireDate").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("q32").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Set ie = Nothing

    End Sub
```

This is what the pop-up window looks like.

[image: Pop-Up Window]

When I right-click in the First Name field and click Inspect Element, this is what I see.

[image]

Comment: "pop-up window" can mean one of multiple types of thing, so you will need to be a little more specific, since we can't see your URL

Comment: It's hard to say much without more information. What does a successful result look like (what you see when  it "works on other websites")? What does the failed result look like (what incorrect output or error messages you see when it "doesn't work in a popup")? And what does your code look like in each case?

Comment: @TimWilliams More info posted.  When I click inspect element, I see a reference to Widget Window.  I don't know if that helps though.

Answer (score 0):

From your image of popup, It looks like it is a model popup which is part of that web page and not a new window.

Please try to refer example below may help you to open new instance of IE and navigate to specific web page and fill the data in popup window.

```
Sub website()

On Error GoTo 0

Dim sURL As String
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

sURL = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pop_up.html"

Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


oBrowser.navigate sURL

Do Until oBrowser.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
oBrowser.Visible = True


oBrowser.Document.getElementById("first_name").Value = "abcd added from VBA..."


'oBrowser.Document.getElementById("Login").Click


End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Note that this is just an example to give you an idea. Further, you need to modify the code example as per your requirement.

other useful references:

(1) [Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)

(2) [IE (Internet Explorer) Automation using Excel VBA](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml)

(3) [Learn to write Excel VBA code to automate your web browser.](http://automatetheweb.net/)

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Here is additional information - I will be as specific as I can. 
The process from start to finish is navigating to the website, entering a user name and password, selecting a company from a list, clicking a button to "add a new participant".  Then a new pop-up window appears, with the form that needs to be completed.  I had the user navigate to the page because I'm still learning, and some users have two-factor authentication credentials.  I will add a picture.

Comment: Please check my modified answer, In which I have shown that how you can enter data to model popup window. Let us know, If you have further questions. We will try to provide suggestions for that.